# Differential Equations; Laplace

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I just started learning Laplace Transfroms and for the most part they make sense but what is really starting to aggravate me is the fact that I don't know where the e^-st comes from. I get that it's the kernel but how do we come to that conclusion and since we call it the kernel, does that mean there are other kernels/null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a wide class of integral transforms with different kernels. Think of it more generally:

$$ \tilde{f}(y) = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x)k(x, y)dx $$

Where $ f(x) $ is your original function, $ k(x,y) $ is the kernel and $ \tilde{f}(y) $ is the transformed function.

When you integrate over $ dx $ (definite integral), the dependence on $ x $ disappears, and the only remaining dependence is the other variable in the kernel, $ y $, since $ x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R} $.

What is really happening is a kind of transformation of coordinates, with some of *kernel smoothing*. The Laplace transform is just a special case which has been shown to have some applications to physics and engineering, and other general sciences.

Picture the function $ f(x) = c $ where $ c \in \mathbb{R} $. If we apply a kernel and evaluate the integral, each small piece we add is scaled by the kernel, so it acts sort of like a filter on $ f(x) $.

Here is a good graphic of what I mean by a filter function. On the left is the result of an integral transform using the two functions on the right:

http://www.hpleym.no/atcm99/images/paper264.gif

That is specifically convolution, just imagine the two functions are stationary for this case (convolution is an integral transform as well).

Comment: So, what your saying is that a Laplace transform is called so just because of the kernel? And if that is true changing the kernel will produce another type of integral transform?

Comment: Yes absolutely, for example see the Fourier transform:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Definition

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the $e^{-st}$ as being an eigenfunction of $\frac{d}{dt}$ with eigenvalue $-s$. In other words, $e_{s}(t)=e^{-st}$ satisfies
$$
                 \frac{d}{dt}e_{s} = -se_{s}.
$$
The Fourier transform is the same kind of thing.

There are other transforms of this type as well. For example, suppose you can find eigenfunctions $\phi_{s}(t)$ to satisfy the following on $[0,\infty)$,
$$
           \left(-\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}+q(t)\right)\phi_{s}(t)=s\phi_{s}(t),\;\;\; \phi_{s}(0)=0
$$
Then you can write a function $f$ on $[0,\infty)$ as
$$
             f(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t')\phi_{s}(t')dt'\right)\phi_{s}(t)d\rho(s),
$$
where $\rho$ is some density function. So you're building up a function from theses basic eigenfunctions $\phi_{s}$, and the coefficient function to do that is
$$
            \int_{0}^{\infty}f(t')\phi_{s}(t')dt' = \int_{0}^{\infty}f(t')K(t',s)dt'
$$
And the inverse transform is also a transform of a similar kind. If you set $q\equiv 0$ then you get the Fourier sine transform and its inverse
$$
              f(t) = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t')\sin(t's)dt'\right)\sin(ts)ds
$$
If you instead set $\phi_{s}'(0)=0$ as the condition, you get the Fourier cosine transform and its inverse
$$
               f(t) = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t')\cos(t's)dt'\right)\cos(ts)ds.
$$
There are many transforms you can build thiis way, just by changing the potential function $q$ and the endpoint condition.

The reason you do this sort of thing is that its a type of "diagonalization" of the differential operator $Lf=-\frac{d^{2}f}{dt^{2}}+qf$. The one transform takes you into a space where the differential operator becomes multiplication by the eigenvalue parameter $s$, which makes it easier to solve problems involving this operator. Then you can get back to the original function, which is a solution of some equation.

The Laplace transform really came out as a tool of Analysis in trying to turn differentiation into muliplication by $s$. It's hard to exactly explain how that evolution took place because it was extremely abstract and untrusted for some time, but that is what happened.

Comment: So, aside from an Introductory Course in Differentials, I will come across Laplace again in other math courses? (Math major here)

Comment: @ElSpiffy : I would expect so. The Laplace transform and the Fourier transform are good tools for studying differential equations, in Physics, in Engineering, and in Math.